Add instructions to versioned transactions
hi i'm using versioned tx but i'm not quite sure how to include instructions. here is my initial transaction code:
    const payload = {
      quoteResponse: quoteData,
      userPublicKey: WALLET_ADDRESS,
      wrapUnwrapSOL: true,
      dynamicComputeUnitLimit: true,
      dynamicSlippage: { maxBps: 300 },
      prioritizationFeeLamports: { priorityLevelWithMaxLamports: { maxLamports: 10000000, priorityLevel: "veryHigh" } },
    };


    const swapResponse = await fetch(SWAP_URL, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify(payload),
    });
    const { swapTransaction } = await swapResponse.json();


    // Decode and sign transaction
    const transactionBuffer = Buffer.from(swapTransaction, 'base64');
    const transaction = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(transactionBuffer);
    transaction.sign([PRIVATE_KEY]);

    // Send transaction
    const txid = await connection.sendRawTransaction(transaction.serialize(), {
      skipPreflight: false,
      preflightCommitment: 'processed',
      maxRetries: 3,
    });

....
would you know how i may push an instruction such as:
MY TRANSACTION.push(
        SystemProgram.transfer({
          fromPubkey: owner.publicKey,
          toPubkey: new PublicKey(ACCOUNT), accounts
          lamports: X,
        }),
      );

to my transaction before it is sent?
Thanks

I think i need to construct a new txn based on this one, put all instructions from this txn to the new one together with ur tip ix, then sign and send the new txn. But not sure how it would work

Keeping in mind the transaction size limit of 1232 bytes, If using a versioned transaction you'll need to create a new transaction message and include your instruction there,
import { TransactionMessage, VersionedTransaction } from "@solana/web3.js";

// -- snip

const transaction = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(transactionBuffer);
transaction.sign([PRIVATE_KEY]);

let swapIx = TransactionMessage.decompile(transaction.message).instructions;

const messageV0 = new TransactionMessage({
    payerKey: owner.publicKey,
    recentBlockhash: (await connection.getLatestBlockhash()).blockhash,
    instructions: [...swapIx, ], // add additional instructions here
}).compileToV0Message();

let tx = new VersionedTransaction(messageV0);

